# CSS3 transition with jQuery .addClass and .removeClass

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a big main navigation panel that I want to animate when it's deploying (expanding).

I'm working with jQuery to trigger the visibility of it by adding/removing the class visible/hidden.

I had to set a delay time to apply the hidden class because the trigger is a button outside of the panel's div. (if I used a rollover on the button, once you rollout the panel will disappear)

The code is this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#menu-item-9').click(function(){
        $('#repair-drop').removeClass('hidden');
        $('#repair-drop').addClass('visible');
    });
$('#repair-drop').on('mouseleave', function(e) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('#repair-drop').removeClass('visible').addClass('hidden');
    }, 600);        

});
});
```

My CSS is as follows

```
.hidden{
    max-height: 0px;
    -webkit-transition: max-height 0.8s;
    -moz-transition: max-height 0.8s;
    transition: max-height 0.8s;

}
.visible{
    max-height: 500px;  
}
```

The transition effect is not working at all.

Comment: you can do animations with the addClass RemoveClass and other things if you use jQueryUI too

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You are adding and removing the class that contains the transition CSS. I recommend moving that to its own rule [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/jzoe0q15/1/).

```
.hidden{
    max-height: 0px;
}
.visible{
    max-height: 500px;  
}

#repair-drop{
    -webkit-transition: max-height 0.8s;
    -moz-transition: max-height 0.8s;
    transition: max-height 0.8s;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't works fine when having content inside the div (http://jsfiddle.net/jzoe0q15/)

Answer (score 20):

I am tired of this issue, better use animation:

```
.container .element.animation  {
    animation: SHW .5s;
    animation-fill-mode: both
}
@keyframes SHW {
    from {
        transform:scale(0.7);
        opacity:0
    }
    to {
        transform: scale(1);
        opacity:1
    }
}
```

Add only to .element class .animation and its working:

```
$('.container .element').addClass('animation');
```

Comment: best performance and easiest implementation of all solutions here, imo.

Answer (score 5):

Don't remove the `.hidden` class; it contains your `transition` styles. Just add and remove the `.visible` class.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#menu-item-9').on('click', function(e) {
        $('#repair-drop').addClass('visible');
    });

    $('#repair-drop').on('mouseleave', function(e) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $('#repair-drop').removeClass('visible');
        }, 600);        
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/LjhNa/

---

That said, you might need to improve your solution to account for users rapidly mousing out of `#repair-drop` and clicking on `#menu-item-9` before it can hide.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#menu-item-9').on('click', function(e) {
        $('#repair-drop').data('shown',true).addClass('visible');
    });

    $('#repair-drop').on('mouseleave', function(e) {
        $('#repair-drop').data('shown',false);
        setTimeout(function() {
            if (!$('#repair-drop').data('shown')) {
                $('#repair-drop').removeClass('visible');
            }
        }, 600);        
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/b8QpB/

Comment: Your answer is very logical, I didn't realize about that, and you're right. Although, I applied it and the transition is not showing

Comment: You'll need to provide some HTML and/or a working demo, then.

Comment: I'm working now with the jquery easing plugin and seems I got it to work

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered using jQuery UI's animation features?  such as

```
jQuery('#menu-item-9').hide({duration:200,effect:'blind'});
```

You could also animate the removal of the class, like

```
jQuery('#menu-item-9').removeClass('hidden', {duration:200,effect:'blind'});
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to make this work using jquery easing plugin. 
Thanks to all for your responses

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#menu-item-9').click(function(){
        $('#repair-drop').removeClass('hide');
        $('#repair-drop').animate({"max-height":"500px", "padding-top":"20px", "opacity":"1"},1500, "easeOutCubic");
    });
$('#repair-drop').on('mouseleave', function(e) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('#repair-drop').animate({"max-height":"0px", "overflow":"hidden", "padding":"0px","opacity":"0"},2000, "easeOutCubic");

    }, 600);        

});
});
```

Comment: Nicely done, but... these days css transitions are considered the way to do animation. Super simple jquery code with add and remove class and then all the animation properties inside css.